# QGIS Action to "enable" (display) a raster layer that is already loaded

Tags: pyqgis, layers

QGIS Action to "enable" (display) a raster layer that is already loaded
QGIS 3.30 under Mac OS X 10.13:

I have a Parcels layer containing polygons showing parcels;
it is selected and checked, i.e., being displayed

I have many Plan-xxx raster layers, each containing a single georeferenced survey map.
These are loaded, but UNchecked, i.e., not being displayed

In my Parcels layer I have an attribute containing the name of the corresponding Plan layer for each polygon in Parcels

I'm looking for a way to have an Action in Parcels which, when clicked on a polygon in Parcels, activates the corresponding Plan; i.e., "checks" the Plan so it displays.

A couple of problems:

a) I cannot figure out how to "check" a layer so it displays

b) when running the following Python script:

```
   layers = iface.mapCanvas().layers() 
     for layer in layers:
       print(layer)
       print(layer.name())
       print(layer.id())
```

it only lists the checked layers, i.e., those being displayed
so I don't know how to connect the Plan name to its corresponding UNchecked layer.

Do you have any suggestions?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the following code in your Python action script.

```py
from qgis.utils import iface

project = QgsProject.instance()
layer_id = '[%@layer_id%]'
fid = [%$id%]
layer_obj = QgsProject().instance().mapLayer(layer_id)
feat = layer_obj.getFeature(fid)
plan_name = feat['Plan_Name']
# Retrieve project layers via name stored in vector attributes
plan_layers = project.mapLayersByName(plan_name)
if plan_layers:
    # Retrieve map layer object
    plan_layer = plan_layers[0]
    # Retrieve layer tree layer object
    ltl = project.layerTreeRoot().findLayer(plan_layer)
    # Get its current check state
    ltl_checked = ltl.itemVisibilityChecked()
    # Set layer visibility to opposite of its current state
    iface.layerTreeView().setLayerVisible(plan_layer, not ltl_checked)
else:
    iface.messageBar().pushMessage('Layer not found')
```

For reference, in my test layer I have a field called 'Plan_Name' which contains the names of the corresponding raster layers loaded in the current project:

[image]

My layer action config looks like this:

[image]

As you see in the following screencast, when you activate the action and click on a vector polygon feature, the corresponding raster layer will be turned on or off (reverse of it's current check state).

[image]

Comment: WOW!  That is a wonderfully complete answer.  I never would have gotten there without Ben W's help.  Many thanks!

Comment: @fgfletcher, that's great! You're welcome :-)